# IIS7.5 PowerShell preloadEnabled

Tags: powershell, iis-7.5

Is it possible I can use PowerShell command (e,g, New-WebSite) to create a web site and set site's preloadEnabled="true"?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've been looking for this too, but couldn't find anything in WebAdministration to set this option. Presumably the approach would be to call New-ItemProperty on the correct WebApplication. Unfortunately, I was unable to get the "default" application for a given website, or to set this property on it. It kinda seems like the WebAdministration module (which enables cmdlets like New-WebSite) was written with earlier versions of IIS in mind, and certainly before the Application Initialization module.

This is a workaround, which forces the setting of these properties by editing the underlying applicationHost.config file. This is a slightly simplified version of a script we're now using. You'll need to run this script as an administrator.

```
# Copy applicationHost.config to the temp directory,
# Edit the file using xml parsing,
# copy the file back, updating the original

$file = "applicationhost.config"
$source = Join-Path "$env:windir" "\system32\inetsrv\config\$file"
$temp = Join-Path "$env:temp" "$([Guid]::NewGuid().ToString())"
$tempFile = Join-Path "$temp" "$file"

#update all applications in websites whose name matches this search term
$search = "website name to search for"

#copy applicationHost.config to  temp directory for edits
#assignments to $null simply silence output
$null = New-Item -itemType Directory -path $temp
$null = Copy-Item "$source" "$temp"

# Load the config file for edits
[Xml]$xml = Get-Content $tempFile

# find sites matching the $search string, enable preload on all applications therein
$applications = $xml.SelectNodes("//sites/site[contains(@name, `"$search`")]/application") 
$applications | % { 
    $_.SetAttribute("preloadEnabled", "true") 
}

#save the updated xml
$xml.Save("$tempFile.warmed")

#overwrite the source with updated xml
Copy-Item "$tempfile.warmed" "$source"

#cleanup temp directory
Remove-Item -recurse $temp
```

Answer (score 29):

This should do the trick. You can use the `get-itemproperty` to verify that it worked. It took me a while to figure out where to find `preloadEnabled` within powershell but if you pipe the site path to `get-member`, then you can work your way from there.

```
import-module webadministration
set-itemproperty IIS:\Sites\SiteName -name applicationDefaults.preloadEnabled -value True
```

Comment: Works perfectly, important here to remember is: preloadEnabled is case-sensitive. Also, I used ([System.Convert]::ToBoolean("True")) instead of $true.

Comment: I also needed to write "applicationDefaults" with the correct case to get it working. Otherwise works fine.

Comment: This is the answer. The trick is adding "applicationDefaults." before "preloadEnabled"

Comment: this works on server 2008 with iis 7 

import-module webadministration
set-itemproperty IIS:\Sites\site-name\application-name -name preloadEnabled -value True

Comment: This script does not seem to affect the same property as the one manipulated in IIS Manager.

Comment: Bad approach. It will set `preloadEnabled` to `True` to **all** applications, defined for the website. Even worse, if you run it again `set-itemproperty IIS:\Sites\SiteName -name applicationDefaults.preloadEnabled -value False` - to reverse the changes, it will set `applicationDefaults.preloadEnabled` to `False`, but for all existing applications this parameter will be kept `True`

Answer (score 10):

This is a bit late, but this will help others...  This worked for me and was a little less verbose.  The key difference is that I removed ApplicationDefaults because I am setting the application, not the defaults here:

```
Set-ItemProperty IIS:\Sites\<siteName>\<applicationName> -name preloadEnabled -value True
```

WHERE: 
'SiteName' might equal Default Web Site
'ApplicationName' might equal MyApplication

Answer (score 8):

There is in fact a way to do this (assuming you have a single application at / that you want to set it for and you know the name of your site):

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll")
$serverManager = (New-Object Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager)
$serverManager.Sites["YOUR_SITE_NAME"].Applications["/"].SetAttributeValue("preloadEnabled", $true)
$serverManager.CommitChanges()
```

Comment: This is the only approach that worked for me when setting the preloadEnabled attribute of a specific web site's "default" application (path="/"). Set-ItemProperty does not seem to be able to set the preloadEnabled attribute for the root application. I have tested this successfully on two platforms: Windows 7 SP1 64-bit w/ IIS 7.5 and the Application Initialization module installed as well as Windows Server 2012 R2 64-bit w/ IIS 8.5. Both environments have Windows Management Framework 5.0 RTM (i.e. Powershell 5.0) installed for their respective platforms.

Answer (score 3):

You can enable preload for the root application of a website like this:

```
$w = New-Item "IIS:\Sites\AAA" -type site –physicalPath "C:\W" -bindings $binding
$w.Collection[0].preloadEnabled = $true
$w | Set-Item
```

Comment: This works, just removed confusing `**` in your code example

Answer (score 1):

I could offer more granular and deterministic approach:

```
# Creating the website:
$website = New-WebSite -Name $WebSiteName -PhysicalPath $WebSiteFolder -ApplicationPool $PoolName

# Setting preload enabled:
Set-WebConfigurationProperty `
    -PSPath "IIS:\" `
    -Filter "/system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='$WebSiteName']/application[@path='/']" `
    -Name "preloadEnabled" `
    -Value $True  # or $False to turn that off
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I wanted to share my insights.

I needed to do this from an Octopus post-deployment script, where my App was in the Site root. I tried all the suggested solutions here and the one from Robert Moore was the only one working for me.

However, I ended up using this which also did the job:

```
$Site = Get-Item IIS:\Sites\<site name>
$Site.applicationDefaults.preloadEnabled = $true
$Site | Set-Item -Verbose
```

**Warning**: Do not do this if you have any Apps in your Site (see comment from @Sergey Nudnov

Comment: Bad approach. It will set `preloadEnabled` to `True` to **all** applications, defined for the website. Even worse, if you run it again `set-itemproperty IIS:\Sites\SiteName -name applicationDefaults.preloadEnabled -value False` - to reverse the changes, it will set `applicationDefaults.preloadEnabled` to `False`, but for all existing applications this parameter will be kept `True`

Comment: @SergeyNudnov I wasn't aware of that, will add a warning and point to your comment. However in my case, there were no applications in any level below the Site root so this isn't an issue for me.